# Pushing to Heroku Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I know this is a common case but I have searched google/stackoverflow and none of the solutions fits. I have this RoR app that I'm trying to push to heroku. First I created `gentle-savannah-1528` (dyno?) and I am trying `git push heroku master` but then I get this error:

```
emmanuels-imac:kal siaW$ git push heroku master
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
emmanuels-imac:kal siaW$
```

I have tried so many soluctions but none works. Can someone please help me save some time. I can't spend anymore time trying to figure out how to push to Heroku.

I already did:

```
emmanuels-imac:kal siaW$ heroku git:remote -a gentle-savannah-1528
emmanuels-imac:kal siaW$ git push heroku master
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
emmanuels-imac:kal siaW$
```

Comment: what is the output of the command `git remote -v`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't created the `remote` for `Heroku`.

Following [these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote), make sure you've done:

`heroku git:remote -a gentle-savannah-1528`

Then try:

`git push heroku master`

Comment: well the funny thing is i did that already. please check my main post's edit.

Comment: What's the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: And you're in a git repository on your local machine, yes?

Comment: yes on my local machine. `emmanuels-imac:kal siaW$ git remote -v
origin http://gentle-savannah-1528.herokuapp.com/ (fetch)
origin http://gentle-savannah-1528.herokuapp.com/ (push)`

Comment: The output of `git remote -v` looks incorrect.  See:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote

Comment: well i did another `heroku create` again and tried to push to heroku and now i get this `emmanuels-imac:kal siaW$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:mighty-brushlands-6367.git'
emmanuels-imac:kal siaW$ `

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43146/discussion-between-cdub-and-siaw23)

Answer (score 0):

The error says « Please make sure you have the correct access rights ». You probably need to upload your public key to Heroku. Simply type this in your terminal:

```
heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

[This page on the Heroku website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) explains how to create one if you don't have one.